What analog component(s) can I replace a relay with
I'm extremely new to electronics and have a college group project to build a traffic light using only analog components (ICs are allowed), my subsection is to design and build the driver unit and a circuit that dims a set of ac lamps by 60% at night.
[edit]
Hi again,
So I've managed to cobble together a circuit with help from the previous answer and that does indeed dim the lamps, although not by 60% as I've yet to work on that, but dims it nonetheless. I used a relay with the comparator to switch between 2 resistors to toggle different light levels, but my professor told me relays aren't allowed, so now I'm in search for a way to replace the relay with a component/ circuit that functions the same as this relay. Note that some resistance values aren't fixed, as I was more concerned with getting a working circuit first and then work out the required values for dimming. I used a clock pulse generator and steady edge generator to activate the circuit for testing, as there is another member's system responsible for turning certain lamps on/off. I started with one lamp to try to get the dimming to work but need to expand to 5 more lamps(6 in total) and each with their own optoisolator circuit as I receive 6 inputs from the timing circuit. I'd also like advice on how to connect those as well, thanks.


Use a photodiode and a triac

what about during a solar eclipse? ... that's not at night

Welcome to the site, but please capitalise properly in your posts. Not doing so is sloppy or lazy, makes the post difficult to read and shows disrespect to those you are asking to give of their time to help you.

@Transistor, thanks for the advice .

@VoltageSpike, how exactly would I add that to the driver unit though, as you can see in the screenshot, I have a triac, but how do I incorporate a photo diode into that circuit to control the light intensity?

"...  as you can see in the screenshot ..." Ehhhm, what screenshot? Thanks for the tidy-up.

How can we help you merge the circuits if we haven't seen the circuits? Show us your triac circuit.

@Transistor, apologies again, I thought the screenshot was uploaded when i posted, I edited now, are you able to see it?

@Mattman944, my apologies, can you see it now?

How much flexibility do you have with the design? Do you have to use 12VAC lamps? Or is the assignment is to marry these circuits as they are with glue circuitry in between? You problem is trivial, but your approach is dubious.

@MOSFET, yeah they have to be ac lamps, these circuits were the only somewhat working circuits I could cobble up, and when i tried to integrate them they didnt function as planned, i.e. the lamps did not dim when the ldr no longer detected light

@OR13N So you're responsible for the dotted box circuit in this answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/707742/optimizing-incandescent-traffic-light-design/707776#707776

@MOSFET, surprisingly enough, this is the same project I'm working on, and to answer your question, yes, but not solely the  dotted box, I'm responsible for designing the entire circuit you included on the right (driver as well as dimmer).
